# Monotouch.Dialog - UISearchBar Tint

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uisearchbar, monotouch.dialog

When I enable the Search bar on a `DialogViewController`, how is the searchbar's tint changed?

```
        EnableSearch = true;
        SearchPlaceholder = "Find station";
        AutoHideSearch = false;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The searchbar in MonoTouch.Dialog is private, you would need to modify your source code to change the TintColor when the searchBar is instantiated.

Another option suggested in the comments is to use:

```
((UISearchBar) TableView.TableHeaderView).TintColor = UIColor.Black;
```

Comment: Most excellent!   May I suggest that you add this information as an answer to this post, so others looking for this information will find it.

Comment: The March 31, 2012 release broke this: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969112/monotouch-dialog-uisearchbar-color

Answer (score 0):

Taking Miguel's help, I found that the `TableHeaderView` containers the `SearchBar` so I could do this to change the `tint` after the `searchBar` is instantiated (thanks):

```
UISearchBar sb = TableView.TableHeaderView as UISearchBar;
if(sb!=null)
   sb.TintColor = UIColor.Black;
```