# MonoTouch.Dialog: UISearchBar Color

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uisearchbar, monotouch.dialog

In the March 31 release of MonoTouch.Dialog we aren't able to set the color of the `UISearchBar` anymore now as there is a new container object with hard coded colors.

Is there a simpler way to change the color of the `UISearchBar` ?

As a work around, I use this (knowing that the UISearchBar is the last added item to the new class `SearchBarBackgroundView`:

```
        SearchBarBackgroundView sb = TableView.TableHeaderView as SearchBarBackgroundView;
        if (sb != null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (sb.Subviews.Count () > 1)
                {
                    UISearchBar bar = sb.Subviews [sb.Subviews.Count () - 1] as UISearchBar;
                    if (bar != null)
                    {
                        bar.BackgroundColor = Settings.AppTintColor;
                        bar.TintColor = Settings.AppTintColor;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ExceptionPublisher.Pub (e, ""); 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a **bad** feature regression. IMO the answer is not about a workaround, the best one would be: use an earlier revision, but finding when/why this occurred and make sure the next releases of MonoTouch does not impose this breaking change to other developers.

The best way to deal with those, since the [MonoTouch.Dialog](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog) assembly is open source, is to track the revision where it occurred. You can see the [history](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/commits/master/MonoTouch.Dialog/DialogViewController.cs) from github and then comment on the entry that cause the issue (e.g. this [one](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/commit/a5a676d8bb89123e200afa4a9442f67fe4884101#MonoTouch.Dialog/DialogViewController.cs) *looks* like a candidate - maybe just because it does too many things in a single patch).

So if the revision before this one works then you add a comment (bottom of the page) about the issue. Everyone following the repository will get an email.

**UPDATE**: The patches that introduced the breaking changes has been reverted.