# Can I customise the Search bar with Monotouch.dialog

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have a custom monotouch dialogviewcontroller created, and I have set:

```
EnableSearch = true
```

however, I am using a background colour of dark grey and I have a black colour UINavigationBar too. So the default search bar that appears in my DialogViewController looks quite out of place.

Is there a way I could customise the colour of this at all, or subclass UISearchBar or something like that to get this search bar to fit with the other colours I am using in my app?

Thanks for any help or pointers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I should have tried the word "tint" in my initial searches before posting this question. The answer to this is on the following question: [Monotouch.Dialog - UISearchBar Tint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622200/monotouch-dialog-uisearchbar-tint)

To summarise what is mentioned in this thread, you just simply cast your TableView.TableHeaderView as UISearchBar and use the TintColor property to set your desired value.

```
((UISearchBar) TableView.TableHeaderView).TintColor = UIColor.Black;
```

:)